Why am I encountering this "#VALUE error" when using BYROW, LAMBDA and INDIRECT function together?
Issue I am using BYROW, LAMBDA and INDIRECT functions together in order to create a dynamic table of content of the entire workbook listing in the first column the sheet name and in the second column the value in specific cell of each workbook (same cell for each as workbook intended to use a defined structure template)
E.g.



Tab
Description




ABC Limited
Nature of operations are...


DEF Co
Nature of operations are...



The first column I am aware how to achieve using name manager and =(GET.WORKBOOK(1))&T(NOW()) etc. This will dynamically update in array format the list of sheets in the workbook.
For the second column I am trying to use a reference to the first column and the indirect formula to get a specific cell from each workbook e.g. A1 from each workbook. I'm using BYROW and and LAMBDA along with indirect since I'm aware that INDIRECT formula does not cater for arrays.
Simplified Formula Demo
I'm including a simplified version of the formula which is just picking up data from the same sheet as I managed to narrow down the issue. It seems that :
This is the formula which doesn't work returning a #VALUE error
=BYROW(TRANSPOSE({"A1","A2"}),LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X)))
This is a workaround I found which is a bit messy and I'd like to avoid
=BYROW(C4#,LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X)))
Note C4# contains array: {"A1","A2"}
Issue encountered
As you can see the main difference is that the second one which works I am referring to C4# an external array, whereas in the first formula I am trying to contain the array inside the BYROW formula, to make the formula more concise and neat.
My goal is to find a way to make the first formula work without having to add the array (C4#) external to the formula.

Your question is incomplete. What would you like to do with the output? Do you want to sum or merge or ?

Please read : How do I ask a good question? . Not sure how your first formula is working. what is that you are looking to return. Post some sample data

This part confuses me: I am trying to ... get cell C2 of all of the sheets in a workbook in an array format. because that's a different question and can be accomplished using 3D reference. Is this your goal, or using the indirect in your question? If you need a 3d reference of the same cell from different sheets, than you don't need volatile INDIRECT

The note
Despite to INDIRECT function, INDIRECT doesn't work with neither more a single cell range nor a dynamic array argument (even if the dynamic array consists of a single value only).
The answer
=BYROW(TRANSPOSE({"A1","A2"}),LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X)))

doesn't work and returns the '#VALUE!' error due to limitation of INDIRECT described above (X gets the rows {"A1"} and {"A2"} which are not accepted by INDIRECT).
I will research the equivalent formula:
=BYROW({"A1";"A2"},LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X)))

It doesn't work instead of =BYROW(C4:C5,LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X))) due to the feature of the BYROW/BYCOL function to process the range or the dynamic array argument differently.
The solution provided by @ScottCraner is
=BYROW({"A1";"A2"},LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(@X)))


Or another solution
=MAP({"A1";"A2"},LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X)))


Explanation of BYROW/BYCOL behavior
BYROW and BYCOL functions have a feature in different processing of the range or the dynamic array argument.

As we can see, BYROW gets an array from each element of the vertical vector dynamic array while it gets a single value per row from the single-column range.
Summary
I can state what behavior of the BYROW (BYCOL) function with a range argument contradicts its description (BYCOL description).

=BYROW(TRANSPOSE({"A1","A2"}),LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(@X))) works.  BYROW sends and array to LAMBDA and INDIRECT cannot use an array.  So you need to force the array into a value.  @ returns the relative reference. =BYROW(TRANSPOSE({"A1","A2"}),LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(INDEX(X,1,1)))) would do the same thing.  MAP sends a value and not an array.

@ScottCraner Super! It looks like a problem I discovered earlier in Excel-365 functions don't work as expected

@ScottCraner While the solution woks, explanation is not correct. What is the difference between =BYROW(C4#,LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X))) and =BYROW({"A1","A2"},LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X)))? The argument is an array in both cases.

The difference is that C4# is a range whereas only {"A1","A2"} is an array, i.e. where C4# is a vertical range, =BYROW(C4#,LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X))) evaluates correctly but =BYROW(TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(C4#)),LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X))) does not. btw since the OP clarified he has a horizontal range, I would suggest =TRANSPOSE(BYCOL(C4#,LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(X)))) to yield the dynamic version of @ScottCraner's output (I don't believe BYROW() was designed for single-row input)

I noticed that from the suggested answers, the output will still be defined to one cell, whereas I want to achieve the output to be a dynamic array. Is there any way I can convert the array  {"A1","A2"} into a range? So that the formula works with dynamic arrays and I can contain the range? @SpectralInstance

#John Have you fully read the answer above? There are two solutions provided. They both produce the array on the dynamic array input.

I tried the first solution using "@" however this is only returning one cell result and not an array which I am seeking. I also tried the second solution but it is not working (Excel error "There is a problem with this formula"). Both solutions haven't helped thus far but I still appreciate all the feedback.

Further to my previous comment, please disregard my comment on the first solution, it in fact worked. Excel was adding an "@" sign after the equals automatically and I was not realising. Now that i removed it the result works. Thank you so much. I am curious though how the MAP solution works as it's not working for me and I am new to the MAP formula. I will then mark as resolved.

Which formula have you tried? This formula from the answer =BYROW({"A1","A2"},LAMBDA(X,INDIRECT(@X))) works and returns the array.

Yes that is the one which worked. Thanks again. However the alternative solution using MAP is not working.

It works, I depicted it, refresh the page in the browser.

Is there any way I can share a snippet? Although I believe you that it works, for some reason it still won't work on my device. I don't have enough point to chat directly. I have the latest version of Excel.

Can you depict the sheet and add the image to your original question? Select the cell with the formula to have it visible in the formula bar.

Do you use the formula with semicolon delimiter as provided, may be? I corrected it for you.

@rotabor Sir, see when click Add Comment below that button click on Help it will give you reference on how to do the formatting in comments. Also what i did is: 1. Open Square Brackets. 2. Enter Topic. 3. Close Square Brackets. 4. Open First Bracket 5. Link. 6. Close First Bracket.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi, the MAP formula works, @rotabor the issue was the delimiter good catch!
